# Getting unique values as a query result

Tags: mysql

I have a many-to-many relation with my database, so I created a sql query which later I will use for search.
Now what I want to do is get a unique values from my search result (unique company names).

This is my query:

```
SELECT agencies.company
    ,agencies.website_url
    ,agencies.STATUS
    ,agencies.size
    ,IndustryData.industry_id
    ,ProfessionData.profession_id
    ,SectorData.sector_id
    ,seniorityData.seniority_id
    ,ZonesData.zone_id
FROM agencies
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT agencies_industries.agency_id
        ,agencies_industries.industry_id
    FROM agencies_industries
    ) AS IndustryData ON agencies.id = IndustryData.agency_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT agencies_professions.agency_id
        ,agencies_professions.profession_id
    FROM agencies_professions
    ) AS ProfessionData ON agencies.id = ProfessionData.agency_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT agencies_sectors.agency_id
        ,agencies_sectors.sector_id
    FROM agencies_sectors
    ) AS SectorData ON agencies.id = SectorData.agency_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT agencies_seniorities.agency_id
        ,agencies_seniorities.seniority_id
    FROM agencies_seniorities
    ) AS SeniorityData ON agencies.id = SeniorityData.agency_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT agencies_zones.agency_id
        ,agencies_zones.zone_id
    FROM agencies_zones
    ) AS ZonesData ON agencies.id = ZonesData.agency_id
WHERE IndustryData.industry_id = 3
    AND ProfessionData.profession_id = 1
```

The result looks like this:

**company, website_url, status, size, industry_id, profession_id, sector_id, seniority_id, zone_id**

1. Nine    nine.com    1   3   3   1   3   2   1
2. Nine    nine.com    1   3   3   1   3   2   5
3. Nine    nine.com    1   3   3   1   3   2   8
4. Nine    nine.com    1   3   3   1   3   5   1
5. Nine    nine.com    1   3   3   1   3   5   5
6. Nine    nine.com    1   3   3   1   3   5   8
7. Ten     ten.com     2   3   3   1   3   1   1
8. Ten     ten.com     2   3   3   1   3   1   3
9. Ten     ten.com     2   3   3   1   3   1   7
10. Ten    ten.com     2   3   3   1   3   3   1
11. Ten    ten.com     2   3   3   1   3   3   3
12. Ten    ten.com     2   3   3   1   3   3   7
13. Ten    ten.com     2   3   3   1   3   5   1
14. Ten    ten.com     2   3   3   1   3   5   3
15. Ten    ten.com     2   3   3   1   3   5   7

I would like to get rid of the repeats of the company names. How do I do that?

Comment: There are lots of ways - what do you want to do with the last two values that vary, though?

Comment: Do you just want the company names or more?

Comment: @RedFilter this is just an example don't worry about the two values that vary - later I will use this code to create search

Comment: @Matschie Company names would be just enough, maybe with id's -> then I would add a buttons to view particular companies and there would be an exact information about agencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `GROUP BY` for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT agencies.company
    ,agencies.website_url
    ,agencies.STATUS
    ,agencies.size
    ,IndustryData.industry_id
    ,ProfessionData.profession_id
    ,SectorData.sector_id
FROM ...
GROUP BY agencies.company
    ,agencies.website_url
    ,agencies.STATUS
    ,agencies.size
    ,IndustryData.industry_id
    ,ProfessionData.profession_id
    ,SectorData.sector_id
```

Comment: Thanks, this is excactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do that with variables and subqueries, as some examples shown here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

But maybe doing this at your code is faster than in your query.